# Unwanted folder creation during SSCERuntime_x64_ENU_40.exe installation

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am installing SSCERuntime_x64_ENU_40.exe in commandline using below arguments. But some unwanted new folders are created like below structure and installer related files exist in it.

**Install Arguments:** “SSCERuntime_x64_ENU_40.exe” /i /q /l “LogFile.log”

**New Folder:** “D:\94990506049abd9dacca6d4a6e”

Is there any way to ignore this new folder creation or change that folder creation to another location (like temp location) when installation?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Muthusamy P.